# Why does my 2012 VW jetta light's turn on all by themselves in the colder months?

Tags: electrical, vw, jetta, cold-weather

I've noticed that my 2012 VW jetta SE lights turn on by themselves and eventually drains the battery in the colder months of Minnesota. when I turn the car on and off, it doesn't fix the issue, but when I let it idle and warm up it does. 
Please help, I replaced the battery. now what? Headlight switch?